My Honey baked ham sweet potato souffle has thawed out- how long to cook?
directions for Honey Baked Ham sweet potato souffle are from frozen and mine are thawed out. How long to cook?

This is impossible to answer without more information – how big is it, what timing is indicated for heating from frozen, and so on.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
